# Can I use Google Auth 2.0 from any origin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-authentication

I develop modal window with React.js, that can be distributed for several sites via some kind of web application market.

So I faced the issue, that for any website, that would install this extension (btw it's builded to a simple html page + couple of js files, so app will be hosted directly on website of even customer), Google auth error will throw exception of invalid origin.

So is there any way to find a workaround for my case?

btw now I'm using react-google-login library

Answer (score 1):

Google allows you to set multiple URIs. Just take a look in the settings.

[image]

Comment: that's not a solution, because I can't handle any origin, that will intall my extension

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand what you trying to achieve. I would make a server to host the api and handle Google auth, so you will have just one origin. And then you write your extension to consume that api.  So even though the extension is on `somewebsite.com ` and `someotherwebsite.com` they will both communicate to google through `oursite.com`

Comment: Thanks, finally I've made the same conclusion  :)